# can't ping from virtualbox ubuntu server --nat connection

Tags: server, virtualbox

i set up an ubuntu server in virtual box following [these](http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=148&cpage=2#comment-7131) and [these](http://adigitalnotepad.com/post/howto-setup-ubuntu-server-on-virtualbox) instructions.My connection worked,also ssh .
 Then, i signed up in dyndns.com ,i configured the router ,but in the port forward i changed the 2222 port to 80 because it couldn’t forward from 2222.My port is open and accepting connections but i don’t have any more connection from the server in the virtual box. 
From virtual box settings->network->port forwarding , i use:
 Host IP :127.0.0.1 , Host port :80 , Guest Port :22 ,Guest IP : its empty.

I am not sure if i am using right the address in /etc/network/interfaces , i use 192.168.0.2 and also this address i use for the firewall rules in the router.
Also,in the server /etc/resolv.conf i put that address and in  /etc/mysql/my.cnf.

I can ping that address but nothing more.(of course neither ssh works)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would change your network connection settings ("Devices" -> "Network Adapters...") from NAT to "Bridged Adapter". You will want your virtual box to get an IP Address from your router and not a separate one from the host machine.

[image: VirtualBox Network settings tab showing attached to, bridged adapter]

This should allow you to use only the router's configuration to poke a port directly to your virtual box on the network.

Comment: When you say strait,you mean from the settings choose instead of nat "not attached"?I tried but still the same

Comment: I mean "Bridged", I've added a screenshot to show you the kind of options available in VirtualBox OSE.

Comment: It gives me"Failed to open a session for the virtual machine UbuntuServer.
Unknown configuration node '//ssh' found in the configuration of IntNet instance #0 (VERR_CFGM_CONFIG_UNKNOWN_NODE).
Unknown error creating VM (VERR_CFGM_CONFIG_UNKNOWN_NODE)."Also, i am not sure if i want nat or bridge.Thanks

Comment: That error is very scary, you may need to report a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you changed your forwarding port from 2222 to 80.  According to VirtualBox in their description of NAT Limitations that won't work:

(https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged)

> Forwarding host ports < 1024 impossible:
>
> On Unix-based hosts (e.g. Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X) it is not possible
>   to bind to ports below 1024 from applications that are not run by
>   root. As a result, if you try to configure such a port forwarding, the
>   VM will refuse to start.